# pattern match with SQL

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I am still new to writing SQL queries. 
I am trying to find all rows that have a specific pattern match that is a combination of a constant_string_1, followed by any combination of integers, followed by another constant_string_2. 
So for ex I am trying to find all rows that match:

- Roger_117788_Maryland
- Roger_188_Maryland
- Roger_211_Maryland

I have tried: 
`select * from cust where cust_string ilike 'Roger_[0-9]_Maryland'`

However that query doesn't generates 0 results. I have also tried using [:digit:] and \d but neither has worked. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1) The `ILIKE` operator doesn't accept POSIX (or even SQL99) regular expressions. 2) Even if it did, your expression would not match any of the examples you provided.

Comment: You're missing the escape character ` \ ` before your underscores  in the regex. In PostgreSQL, the underscore is the single character wild card.

Comment: Use `~` instead of `ILIKE`, and correct your expression for accepting multiple digits instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

You can work this with just "%". Ilike may cause issues, so you can use "like" after transforming your column to lower case to match all cases.

```
select * from cust where lower(cust_string) like 'roger%maryland';
```

Comment: But % will match any character. DigiEnthu wants a wildcard that will only match on digits. You're also not accounting for the underscore characters in the "constant" parts of the string.

Comment: Thanks- yes  % couldn't be used here. Also with regexp_instr() the underscore did not require an escape character. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked. I ended up using regexp_instr, but it was the multiple-digit match was where my query was not giving the results.

`select * from cust where regexp_instr(cust_string, '^(Roger_)[0-9]{1,10}__Maryland$') > 0'`

This did two things. One it achieved the result set above, i.e. Roger_188_Maryland, etc. But it also removed any multiple occurrences of the patterns, so for ex it eliminated a multi-match like Roger_188_Roger_211_Maryland. Thanks everyone for your help.